# calculation of the limit thickness of a tank varying the pressure and the radius and matrix construction on matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to write a program on matlab to analyze the effect of the pressure on the minimal thickness for a pressure vessel for a pressure range between 1 and 300 bar and for different L/R ratios

The following code creates a vector called s_lim calculated with the different thicknesses:

```
`clear all; clc;
 L_in = 1; % Internal radius in m
 L_R_in = 1; % L/R ratio in m

 %material properties
 Sy = 2513; % Yield strength in bar
 Su = 5521; % Ultimate tensile strength in bar
 Density = 0.008027; % kg/m^3
 Cost = 18.94; % $/kg % Wall thickness calculation

 p_tank = 1:300; % Tank pressure in bar 
 R_in = 1;
 V_in = 1;
 R_in = 1;
 s_lim = ones(length(p_tank),1);
 s_Sy = ones(length(p_tank),1);
 s_Su = ones(length(p_tank),1);
 SF = 2; % Safety factor s_Sy = p_tank \* R_in / Sy \* 1.5; % Minimum thickness based on yield strength       

 for i = 1:length(p_tank)
 s_Sy(i) = p_tank(i) .\* R_in / Sy \* 1.5; % Minimum thickness based on yield strength in bar 
 if           (s_Su \< s_Sy)
 s_Su(i) = p_tank(i).\* R_in / Sy \* SF; % Minimum thickness based on ultimate tensile strength in bar  
 s_lim(i) = s_Su(i); % Limiting criterion is burst = ultimate strength
 disp('burst');
 else
 s_lim(i) = s_Sy(i); % Limiting criterion is proof = yield strength
 disp('proof');
 end
 end`
```

The following is the other part that calculates the external radius of the tank for different L/R ratios,

```
 `clear all;clc;
 p_tank = 1;
 L_in = 1;
 L_R_in = 1: 1000;
 R_in = ones(1,length(L_R_in));
 V_in = ones(1,length(L_R_in));
 for i = 1:length(p_tank)
 for j = 1: length(L_R_in)
 R_in(j) = L_in./L_R_in(j); % Length in m
 V_in(j) = 4/3*pi.R_in(j).^3 + (L_in - 2 .* R_in(j)) . pi .\* R_in(j).^2; % m^3 plot(L_in, V_in);
 end
 end`
```

I would like to mix the two codes to creating a matrix R_ext(i,j) = R_in +s_lim where on every row I have the different R_ext calculated for every pressure between 1 and 300 bar, while on every column I have the dependance on the L/R ratio (here called L_R_in).

It shouldn't be hard it is just that I'm approaching coding, I hope it is clear

I tried to use a solution like
`for i = 1 :length(p_tank) for j = 1 :length(L_R_in) s_Sy (i,j) = p_tank(i,j) .\* R_in(i,j) / Sy \* 1.5; ... ... end end`

But it didn'y work

Comment: First thing about learning to program: "But it didn'y work" is not a valid explanation, you need to figure out (and explain to us) why it didn't work.

Comment: To elaborate: There was either an error message, and these are very descriptive and useful in MATLAB, or you didn't get the results you expected, in which case you should explain what you got and what you expected.